# javascript - count spaces before first character of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

What is the best way to count how many spaces before the fist character of a string?

```
str0 = 'nospaces even with other spaces still bring back zero';
str1 = ' onespace do not care about other spaces';
str2 = '  twospaces';
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to count the spaces? You know about trim right?

Comment: i have a text box for quick edit of json string and i need to know how many spaces before the string starts to figure out where it is in the object

Comment: You could use the regex `/^\s+/` and count using `str0.match(/^\s+/)[0].length`

Comment: Try to use jQuery and add ltrim functions in combination with suggested solution below. A reference link: http://www.somacon.com/p355.php

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

```
'    foo'.search(/\S/);  // 4, index of first non whitespace char
```

EDIT:
You can search for "Non whitespace characters, OR end of input" to avoid checking for -1.

```
'    '.search(/\S|$/)
```

Comment: I like this. It does require that at least one non-whitespace char appears, but it's nice and clean. I suggest this addition: `'    '.search(/\S|$/)` which will account for strings which do not have a non-whitespace char.

Comment: Yeah, it will return -1 if there is no match for \S.

Comment: With or without my addition, depending on the OP's needs, I like this answer better than my own. Good thinking.

Comment: Yeah, that is a nice way to handle it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: there will be no case of all white space but still nice to know

Comment: You can deal with all variations with:
```var offset = (' '+str.search(/\S|$/) -1;```

Answer (score 10):

Using the following regex:

```
/^\s*/
```

in `String.prototype.match()` will result in an array with a single item, the length of which will tell you how many whitespace chars there were at the start of the string.

```
pttrn = /^\s*/;

str0 = 'nospaces';
len0 = str0.match(pttrn)[0].length;

str1 = ' onespace do not care about other spaces';
len1 = str1.match(pttrn)[0].length;

str2 = '  twospaces';
len2 = str2.match(pttrn)[0].length;
```

Remember that this will also match tab chars, each of which will count as one.

Comment: have to wait 6 min to answer

Comment: Take a look at my comment on @folkol's answer, and then accept that answer. I like that solution better. You can determine whether you need my addition or not depending upon your circumstances and needs, but overall it's cleaner.

Comment: ya, finding index was pretty slick indeed. I'll never look at a string the same.

Answer (score 8):

You could use trimLeft() as follows

```
myString.length - myString.trimLeft().length
```

Proof it works:

```js
let myString = '       hello there '

let spacesAtStart = myString.length - myString.trimLeft().length

console.log(spacesAtStart)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/TrimLeft

Comment: If you need to support IE, `trimLeft` is not an option. Just use the regex solutions above. Otherwise, this is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

```
str0 = 'nospaces';
str1 = ' onespace do not care about other spaces';
str2 = '  twospaces';

arr_str0 = str0.match(/^[\s]*/g);
count1 = arr_str0[0].length;
console.log(count1);

arr_str1 = str1.match(/^[\s]*/g);
count2 = arr_str1[0].length;
console.log(count2);

arr_str2 = str2.match(/^[\s]*/g);
count3 = arr_str2[0].length;
console.log(count3);
```

Here:
I have used **regular expression** to **count the number of spaces** before the fist character of a string.

```
^ : start of string.
\s : for space
[ : beginning of character group
] : end of character group
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.match(/^\s*/)[0].length
```

str is the string.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but just for giving a different answer

```
let myString     = "     string";
let count_spaces = myString.length - myString.trim().length;
```

Note that if the string has spaces at the end will also be added.

Comment: Good idea. But its explicit asked to count spaces at the beginning of the string. So why not use `trimStart()` instead of `trim()`?

Comment: Yes! you are right It can also be used, as also trimEnd() for other cases, ofc.